# What CSS/HTML - function shoud I look after?

Tags: html, css

In the wordpress-theme [Avada](http://theme-fusion.com/avada/travel/) (A demo site) I can see that they're using some background-effect for overlapping both backgrounds and text-elements at the same time. The first heading is overlapped by the "Who we are" section. How do they do this?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the `div` with the class `tfs-slider flexslider main-flex`

```
<div class="tfs-slider flexslider main-flex" ...>
```

You will notice that it has the attribute [`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). This means that it does not scroll with the content. In addition, they have changed the [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) properties of various elements so that it stays beneath the menu at the top and the content that flows up over it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this resumes down to this CSS property:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Here I have a basic example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/1j3w8ru6/

Comment: Yes, I've tried this and i can't figure it out how they do with the text-element. When I try the text is not overlayed by the "second" div.

Comment: The second `div` is not overlapping the first one. This is what it seems. The text over the image is inside the first `div`. Play with the example I've made to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a really simple working example](https://jsfiddle.net/t8kn1nch/8/)

What we are doing here is setting the position of the first heading to "fixed", pushing the content just below the screen with "margin-top", and setting the content's z-index to a higher value than that of the first heading.

Here is the CSS:

```
html,
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#heading {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#000000;
    z-index:2;
}

#content {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:100%;
}
```